# Inheritance and InputBox

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

So I have a super class called Factorial and two subclasses called Fibonacci and Arithmetic. In my main super class which I call the method using a polymorphic array from my main class, I have an input box inquiry that I want to only show up once, but instead it shows up multiple times. Is there anyway I can stop this? My main class is called PolyMorphism. I know it's tedious but it's the way I made the program and want it to be :p

```
public class Polymorphism {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Factorial arrayObject[] = new Factorial[3];
            arrayObject[0] = new Factorial();
            arrayObject[1] = new Fibonacci();
            arrayObject[2] = new Arithmetic();

for(int x=0;x<arrayObject.length;++x){
        arrayObject[x].sequence();
    }

public class Factorial extends JFrame {
//this input box shows up 3 times when I launch.
public final String valueInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number between 1 and 20.");
public void sequence(){

    System.out.println("Factorial:");
    System.out.println(fact(Integer.valueOf(valueInput)));

public static long fact (int n){
    if (n <= 1){
        return 1;
    }else
        return n * fact(n-1);
}

public class Fibonacci extends Factorial {
public void sequence(){
    int inputValue = Integer.parseInt(valueInput);
    System.out.println("Fibonacci Sequence");
    /**for (int value = 0; value < inputValue; value++){
        System.out.println(fibonacciSequence(value));
    } **/
    System.out.println(fibonacciSequence(inputValue));
}

public static long fibonacciSequence(int v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v == 0) {
            return 0;
        }else if (v <= 2){
            return 1;
        }

        long fibonacci = fibonacciSequence(v - 1) + fibonacciSequence(v-2);
        return fibonacci;
}
```

}

The comment with the problem is under the Factorial class, and disregard the JFrame for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Factorial` class, you have this:

```
public final String valueInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number between 1 and 20.");
```

Which means every time you create an instance of it or a subclass, that input dialog will pop up.

The answer is: Don't do that.

Put it in a method and call the method when you want the input dialog to show.

Comment: What would the method be? static,void,string? (Such an amateur lol)

Comment: Honestly, looking at your code I really don't know what it is you're trying to do. You're extending `JFrame` but aren't using these as GUI components. If you only want one input dialog, then just do it in `Main()` and pass the input to your classes via their constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Each `Factorial` instance (of which you have three) has its own `valueInput` property, so the behavior is as expected. You could make this field `static` (and therefore shared), but it's still not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

It's most likely the case that you should be separating the input display from the `Factorial` implementation entirely.

Comment: Thanks, static fixed the problem! Really appreciate it!